# Getting a strange error about chunked message not chunked in a response

Tags: php, sockets, curl, zend-framework2, php-5.5

The full error is `exception 'Zend\Http\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'Error parsing body - doesn't seem to be a chunked message' in /usr/share/php/ZendFW249/Zend/Http/Response.php:488
...
...
/usr/share/php/ZendFW249/Zend/Http/Response.php(342): Zend\Http\Response->decodeChunkedBody('\x1F\x8B\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\xFF\xFF...')`

I am calling over SSL and using cURL as the adapter. If I use ZF1 with the same params, it works fine.

What is this chunked error message means?

(below, my client configurations)

```
 $config_client = array(
            'adapter' => 'Zend\Http\Client\Adapter\Curl',
            'maxredirects' => 1,
            'timeout'      => 5,
            'useragent'    => 'MyUserAgent'
    );
 $client = new Zend\Http\Client($uri,$config_client);
 $response = $client->send();
 $response->getBody();//HERE I GET THE ERROR!
```

========== UPDATE =============
This might be to some miss configuration on the server I am trying to reach. The request is https, and it seems the response was not decoded properly, either a bug on the cURL adapter or something on the other side.
Once I switched back to using socket, and added to the Http Client configuration the following (ignoring peer verification, which requires the peer to give me his info)
 `'sslverifypeer' => false,` It was all fine.

Comment: Is the response header `Transfer-Encoding:chunked` present on your received response?

Comment: yes. I also was able to figure part of the problem. Updated in question